# How to set state on child component?

Tags: react-native

I have a component that renders out a list of buttons, lets call this 'ButtonList'. When one of the buttons is clicked, the event is bubbled up like so:

```
<ButtonList onButtonPressed={(mins) => { console.log(mins); }} />
```

In response to this, I want to hide that ButtonList and show another component that is currently hidden. The ButtonList has some state such as "state { visible: true }" that I want to toggle that stops it rendering. How do I make a call to toggle the state of that ButtonList and then also call my other component in this view to also toggle its visible state to show?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  swappingComponentsExample = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.showButtonList ? (
          <ButtonList
            onButtonPressed={mins => {
              this.setState({showButtonList: false});
              console.log(mins);
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <OtherComponent />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  // Renders both components but passes style override to hide the object
  // ButtonList/OtherComponent are not destroyed and recreated using this method
  hidingExample = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <ButtonList
          onButtonPressed={mins => {
            this.setState({showButtonList: false});
            console.log(mins);
          }}
          style={!this.state.showButtonList && {display: 'none'}}
        />

        <OtherComponent
          style={this.state.showButtonList && {display: 'none'}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Looking at this, I suspect I was thinking about state wrong. So hiding/showing components is handled by the parent component that is using them. Is there ever a time when we need to call a function defined in a child component, if so, how is this done?

Comment: You can pass through a prop to child that you call child's ref prop with so the parent has ref to it but that gets messy. Passing props to children to trigger a function call is how I manage most of my situations. In the children you use lifecycle methods to monitor changes, `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`. Something like `if (this.props.showing !== nextProps.showing) runFunctionThatOccursWhenShowingChanges();`